# Angular Post api with php sends query successfuly but doesnt reach .subscribe code

Tags: php, angular, api, post

Angular Post api with php sends query successfuly to the data base but doesnt reach .subscribe code after that :

Here is my code in my comp:

```
 postdata(data:any)  
   {
     this.DataService.Userregister(data).subscribe(data=>{console.log('success');})
   };
```

and here is php code  :

```
<?php
include_once("db_connection.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
   {
       $request =json_decode($postdata);

       $email = trim($request->email);
       $password = trim($request->passw);
       $username =trim($request->name);
       $fname =trim($request->fname);
       

       $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Email,Passw,u_name,fname) 
       VALUES ('$email','$password','$username', '$fname') ";


       if( $conn->query($sql)===TRUE)
           {
               $res = "Success";
               echo json_encode($res);
           }
           else{
               $res = "Faild";
               echo json_encode($res);
           }

   }

?>
```

Comment: So what does the network tab in your browser console show?

Comment: It does show the register echos Success

Comment: Please show the code for `this.DataService.Userregister`.

Comment: public Userregister(user:Users):Observable<ApiService>
            {
               

                return this.httpClient.post<ApiService>(this.baseUrl+'regesiter.php',user);

            }